# Can all recursion functions be converted to iterative functions in Python?

Tags: python, recursion

For instance, can this be converted into iterative when mutable arguments are used?

```
        def update_dict(data_dct, record_dct) -> None:
            def update_recursive(a, b):
                if isinstance(b, dict):
                    for key in b.keys():
                        if isinstance(b[key], dict):
                            update_recursive(a[key], b[key])
                        else:
                            a[key].append(b[key])
                else:
                    a.append(b)
            update_recursive(data_dct, record_dct)
```

I've tried using iterative approach such as

```
        def non_recursive_version(data_dct, record_dct) -> None:
            a = data_dct
            b = record_dct
            
            while True:
                if isinstance(b, dict):
                    for k in b.keys():
                        if isinstance(b[k], dict):
                            b = b[k]
                            ....
                else:
                    a.append(b)
```

Comment: All recursive functions can be converted to iterative functions, period.  This might be more or less natural.  At minimum, an explicit data structure can be used in place of a call stack.  In Python, a list of tuples or of lists or of some appropriate class type would be the natural choice for such a data structure.

Comment: I believe there's a chapter on this topic in SICP. It's not specific to a particular language, although some languages make it easier than others.